# Conditional RB Tree union

Tags: algorithms, graphs

**Input:** 2 RB Trees A B, so that both values in a certain range, so that B's range is smaller than A in both sides.  Ex. B's range can be [100...200] and A's range is [0...1000]
**Output:** Unite A and B to one RB Tree AB.

How can I unite these 2 trees in $O(log(n))$ time and with additional space $O(1)$?

I have tried splitting tree A into 3 trees A1,A2,A3, so that:   A1 < A2 , B < A3
A2 contains all that values that are equal-bigger than Min(B) and smaller-equal to Max(B).
I did it using the RB Tree Split algorithm, and all the splitting sums up to $O(log(n))$ time.

Now I know what to do with A1 and A3 but what should I do with A2 and B?  I know I should use the fact that **B contains A2's range** but how does it help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. As shown by [Brown and Tarjan on the first page of "A Fast Merging Algorithm"](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/77/625/CS-TR-77-625.pdf), merging two sequences with overlapping ranges has a worst-case bound of $\Theta (m \lg (n/m))$ comparisons.